# Store values generated after an execution while executing the notebook again

Tags: python

Quick question here.

Let's say I have a notebook with 3 inputs that I set manualy:

```
input1 = 3
input2 = "a"
input3 = 10.5
```

Everytime I run the notebook, I change the inputs.

Is there a way where I could store my inputs 3,"a",10.5 somwhere so I can keep track on the different inputs I used even though I'll run my notebook again with new inputs?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it "store" feature for IPython;

```
sample_field = 10
%store sample_field
```

After that when you need to load your old variables, you just need to use;

```
%store -r
```

for more details;
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html